# Python test to check instance type

Tags: python, testing

I want to use unittest in python to check if a method returns object of the right class.

Every example in the web shows tests for 'type' returned.

For example, to check for  `<type 'list'>` or   `<type 'type'>` , we could use:

```
self.assertIsInstance(result, list)
self.assertIsInstance(result[0], tuple)
```

What I am looking for is an example to check for `<class'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query'>`

Would appreciate any help. Thankyou.

Comment: ...what's the problem, then? Just pass the query class to `isinstance`.

Comment: I think `isInstance` is not the correct method to use. Instead `assertIs` works fine.

Comment: TL;DR - use `assert isinstance(x, int)`

Answer (score 64):

You could use `assertIsInstance()`, presumably using [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) which is the recommended function for testing types. You could also `assertIs()` or `assertTrue()` combined with `type()` depending on the context:

```
#assert.py
import unittest

class TestType(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
      self.number = 1

  def test_assert_true(self):
      self.assertTrue(type(self.number) is int)

  def test_assert_is_instance(self):
      self.assertIsInstance(self.number, int)

  def test_assert_is_with_type(self):
      self.assertIs(type(self.number), int)

  def test_assert_is(self):
      self.assertIs(self.number, int)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


$ python assert.py 

test_assert_is (__main__.TestType) ... FAIL
test_assert_is_instance (__main__.TestType) ... ok
test_assert_is_with_type (__main__.TestType) ... ok
test_assert_true (__main__.TestType) ... ok

======================================================================
FAIL: test_assert_is (__main__.TestType)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assert.py", line 19, in test_assert_is
    self.assertIs(self.number, int)
AssertionError: 1 is not <type 'int'>

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

The assertion error of the `test_assert_is(self)` might lead one to believe the type of 1 is not integer however it's comparing the object represented by 1 and the object that describes the type of an integer. This is most likely why `isinstance()` is preferred since it's more verbose about what it's checking and less typing is involved, so in general less error prone.

Comment: `assertIs` did the job!!. Thanks.

Comment: @BrockHargreaves The results might be easier to understand as three separate tests. (`test_assert_true`, `test_assert_is_instance`, and `test_assert_is`)

Answer (score 14):

This should work:

```
self.assertIsInstance(result, sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query)
```

You need to have `import sqlalchemy` in the file.

Comment: I forgot to use the import statement. Thanks for that. However, I think `assertIsInstance` is not the right test method to use. It returned this error: `AssertionError: <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query'> is not an instance of <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query'>
` . Totally doesnt make sense, but @Brock Hargreaves 's method did the trick.