# Testing python class object instances

Tags: python, django, class, oop

I have this function that I want to test:

```py
def get_django_model(django_model):
    try:
        app_config = apps.get_app_config("myapp")
        model = app_config.get_model(django_model)
        return model
    except Exception:
        raise DjangoModelMissing(f"Missing django model: {django_model}")
```

And here is my test:

```py
class ModelInstanceTest(TestCase):
    def test_get_django_model(self):
        model_class = get_djagno_model("Foo")
        self.assertIsInstance(model_class, models.Foo)
```

The above test fails, saying `AssertionError: <class 'models.Foo'> is not an instance of <class 'models.Foo'>`.

However if I replace `assertIsInstance` with `assertIs` the test passes.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

This post is related, but doesn't really explain the different results: [Python test to check instance type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657463/python-test-to-check-instance-type/33657562).

Comment: A class is indeed *not* an instance of that class.

Comment: You also have a typo in your test `get_djagno_model` (django)

Answer (score 2):

Your `get_django_model` function returns a reference to the *class*, not an object (instance) of that class. So it does not return a `Foo` *object*, it returns a reference to the `Foo` class.

Therefore the `model_class` is indeed equal to `models.Foo`, but *not* an instance of `models.Foo`. It is however an instance of `type`, so you can check that:

```
class ModelInstanceTest(TestCase):

    def test_get_django_model(self):
        model_class = get_djagno_model('Foo')
        self.assertIsInstance(model_class, type)
        self.assertEqual(model_class, models.Foo)
```

Comment: When you say it returns a reference to the class, is that the same thing as saying it returns a metaclass?

Comment: @dwvldg: well the type of a class is a meta-class. So yes, you can say that `model_class` is an object of a meta-class.

Comment: So is `type` and `meta-class` the same thing? In other words, is `self.assertIsInstance(model_class, type)` just saying that `model_class` is an instance of a meta-class? Is there another way to test if something is an instance of a meta-class?

Comment: @dwvldg: but there is no clear distinction, since in Python everything is an object. The type of `type` is `type`, etc. so you can say that the "meta-hierarchy" goes on until infinity.