# Can I ensure return_value types are compatible with the type hints on the method being mocked?

Tags: python, unit-testing, type-hinting, python-typing

Say I have a unit test which mocks out some class `A` to return a custom value. I want to be able to change the value returned by the mocked `A` instance but I definitely don't want to accidentally change the type of the return value and cause my test to inadvertently check for the wrong thing.

For example, take the below code:

```
import datetime
import unittest
import unittest.mock

class A:
    def foo(self, getter):
        return getter.get_time() == '2020-01-01'

class Getter:
    def get_time(self) -> datetime.datetime:
        return datetime.datetime(2020,1,1)

@unittest.mock.patch("__main__.Getter", autospec=True)
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_case_1(self, Getter):
        getter = Getter()
        getter.get_time.return_value = '2020-01-01'
        
        a = A()
        self.assertTrue(a.foo(getter))

test_case = MyTestCase()
test_case.test_case_1()
```

In the above unit test, we are supposed to check that the time matches '2020-01-01', but we've set the `return_value` of `get_time` to be a string, so the test succeeds even though that violates the return type hint of `get_time` (which returns a `datetime`) so the actual code could never work. Is there a way for unittest/mock to pick this up and tell me that I've incorrectly set `return_type` to a value that's incompatible with the type hint on the method?

Comment: @python_user I don't have mypy set up at the moment - would it pick this up though? I don't know if it would see it as a type hint violation since `get_time` (and presumably the hints that came with it) have been replaced. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: can't you add a `assert isinstance(o, datetime)` test in your test sequence, that one should pick-up on a bad mockup I guess [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657463/python-test-to-check-instance-type ]